# Open sets in space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I read in Thomas Calculus (chapter 14.1):

> Examples of  open sets in space include the interior of a sphere, the
>   open half-space $z > 0$, the first octant (where  x,  y, and  z are
>   all positive), and space itself.

I thought the space itself is both open and closed in space. Am I wrong?

Comment: If something is open and closed, then it is in particular open.

Comment: You're right, as is the empty space.

Comment: that is, you are right, and Thomas is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the whole space is both closed and open. So is the empty set. In fact, the whole space and the empty set are the only subsets of the whole space which are both closed and open. In particular, yes, you are right.

But, also in particular, the whole space is open. So, Thomas is right too.

Comment: Thank you. Omitting saying that it is also closed, might create some confusion, especially when you group it with cases that are only open.